# Windows media player sort automatically by rating on startup

Tags: windows-media-player

I want my Windows Media Player to open with sorting done on the basis of rating by default, currently its on the basis of Album name. The reason why I don't want to just click on the top bar to sort on the basis of rating is that my music library is 37GB and it takes WMP around 5 seconds to get done rearranging, and I dislike that. 
Its WMP12 with Windows 7
Thanks.